# Fork versus branch for an addon that target mutliple version of a product?

Tags: git, git-fork

I'm building some addons to a commercial product.

My addons can target multiple versions of the commercial product.

Each version of the addons has slight differences. Around 95% of the code is identical. There are few features that require specific version of the product, and some path has to be changed between versions.

I'd like to store my sources in a git repository but I don't know if I should handle versions of the addon in separate branches, or in separate forks.

1st approach: one repo with these branches:

- dev-v1 (dev branch for V1 of the product)
- master-v1 (master branch for V1 of the product)
- dev-v2 (dev branch for V2 of the product)
- master-v2 (master branch for V2 of the product)
- bugfix/XXXX specific branch for a bugfix. Will have to merge it twice for each product version
- feature/XXXX specific branch for a new feature. Will have to merge it twice for each product version

This should work but I fear having a mess of branches

2nd approach: two repos (repoV1 and repoV2)

- dev
- master
- bugfix/XXXX
- feature/XXXX

and relying on PR to pass code from one version of the product to another

Any advice ?

PS: a bit of background if it matters:

I'm building SharePoint addons that can target either SP2013 or SP2016. Most of the code is C# code built with Visual Studio.

Differences are mostly these ones:

- Version of referenced assemblies. This includes references in csproj files and a bunch of references in aspx and ascx files (and a few other files)
- Some artifacts only available in one or the other version, that shouldn't be included in the two versions

Comment: Are the differences for each version differences in data or differences in logic?

Comment: What's wrong with having many branches?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: the addon should follow rigorous process because of the commercial nature of our addon; That's why I'd like to follow gitflow principles (and I'm not sure it's possible). This will lead to many/many branches and leads to confusion in managing these branches

Comment: My confusion is to why your product is having V1 and V2 developed side-by-side...?

Answer (score 1):

If you can separate the differences between the two versions into data, then a third option is to have a configuration file for each version. This will allow you to keep a single repo with all the code for both versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code itself should be differrent. Actually this may be handled by tweaking the csproj file, but this is non trivial and some cases are hard to implement

Answer (score 1):

Gitflow is useful if all code in your repository belongs to the same release cycle. If you have some deliverables on an independent release cycle, it doesn't work as well.

My preferred way to get only one release cycle per repository, would be to make sure all versions of your addon can be build with the code from the same branch. E.g. have a project with the 95% common code, and small projects that contain the differences, import the common project and build the addon. Whether this is feasible, depends on your code. Doesn't Visual Studio have something like build configurations, normally used to be able to create debug or release, 32bit or 64bit deliverables from the same code?

The other way is to duplicate the develop and master branches within the same repository, as you propose. Of course you can clone the upstream repository twice and perform `git flow init` on each clone with different choices for the names of the develop and master branches. Note that not only would you need to merge the feature branches twice, as you say, but you also need to start them twice. Because `git flow feature start` branches from either of your two develop branches, and `git flow feature finish` deletes the branch, you will need two feature branches as well and cherry-pick your commits from one to the other.

Your other proposal, forking the repository, would also require cherry-picking your commits from one repository to the other. But you can run the regular gitflow process.

Or you can not use gitflow. E.g. keep a branch for all older releases you still support, develop for the newest release, and back-port changes to the older releases. Isn't this what Google does with the Android source code?